# Can I get enumerators demangled using their identifier?

Tags: c++, gcc, symbols, abi

Suppose I've written the following:

```
enum class Color { Red, Green, Blue, };
template <Color c> Color foo() { return c; }
template Color foo<Color::Green>();
```

and compiled it. When I look at an objdump of my compiled code, I get:

```
[einpoklum@myhost /tmp]$ objdump -t f.o  | grep "\.text\." | sed 's/^.*\.text\.//;' | c++filt
Color foo<(Color)1>()
Color foo<(Color)1>()   000000000000000b Color foo<(Color)1>()
```

And if I use `abi::__cxa_demangle()` for `<cxxabi.h>` (GCC; maybe it's different with your compiler), it's also similar - `(Color)0` or `Color)1` are the template parameters, not `Red` or `Green` nor `Color::Red` or `Color::Green`.

Obviously, I can't have names mangled the way I like them. But - I would really like to be able to obtain (or write?) a variant of the demangling call which instead of `"Color foo<(Color)1>()"` returns `"Color foo<(Color:Green>()"` (or `"Color foo<(Green>()"`. Is this doable?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux: See my edit.

Comment: check the answer, please

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible for object files with debug info - section .debug_info contains info about `enum class Color`, it requires some tool to read ELF debug info, parse data semantically and apply/pass info to the c++filt. I don't know if such tools exist or not (maybe, in the GDB it is all glued together)

It is pretty much impossible in general with object files compiled with optimization, or with stripped debug info - information about `enum class Color` is just NOT there...

From optimized build

```
objdump -s aaa.o

aaa.o:     file format pe-x86-64

Contents of section .text$_Z3fooIL5Color1EES0_v:
 0000 554889e5 b8010000 005dc390 90909090  UH.......]......
Contents of section .xdata$_Z3fooIL5Color1EES0_v:
 0000 01040205 04030150                    .......P
Contents of section .pdata$_Z3fooIL5Color1EES0_v:
 0000 00000000 0b000000 00000000           ............
Contents of section .rdata$zzz:
 0000 4743433a 20287838 365f3634 2d706f73  GCC: (x86_64-pos
 0010 69782d73 65682d72 6576302c 20427569  ix-seh-rev0, Bui
 0020 6c742062 79204d69 6e47572d 57363420  lt by MinGW-W64
 0030 70726f6a 65637429 20352e33 2e300000  project) 5.3.0..
```

Debug build has partial contents of section .debug_info:

```
 0070 00000000 00000000 00000002 436f6c6f  ............Colo
 0080 720004a3 00000001 01a30000 00035265  r.............Re
 0090 64000003 47726565 6e000103 426c7565  d...Green...Blue
 00a0 00020004 0405696e 74000566 6f6f3c28  ......int..foo<(
 00b0 436f6c6f 7229313e 0001065f 5a33666f  Color)1>..._Z3fo
 00c0 6f494c35 436f6c6f 72314545 53305f76  oIL5Color1EES0_v
 00d0 007b0000 00000000 00000000 000b0000  .{..............
 00e0 00000000 00019c06 63007b00 00000100  ........c.{.....
 00f0 00
```